# I have a empty space I can't remove

Tags: html, forms, css, html-table, space

I can't find any relevant CSS padding, margins, etc. causing this empty space.

The main page has a middle bar(testimonials) portion that when removed for the sub pages still leaves a noticeable empty space. The elements below are positioned relatively in two columns but they're moving up pushing up.

Main page

```
http://teetime.comeze.com/
```

Sub page example:

```
http://teetime.comeze.com/pestcontrol.html
```

Relevant  CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1030px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    z-index: 2;
}

.header {


}

.content {
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#apDiv5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 942px;
    height: 322px;
    z-index: 1;
    clear: both;
}


.column1 {
    height: 700px;
    width: 490px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 17px;
}

.column2 {
    height: 700px;
    width: 480px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border: none;

}
.form {
    font-family: kreon;
    line-height: normal;
    height: 363px;
    width: 293px;
    /* [disabled]padding-left: 600px; */
    font-size: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    text-indent: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #700CAF;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    background-image: url(teetimefinal.png);

#mail {
    left: 600px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is html code (from end of header to start of the two columns):

```
 <div class="content">
  <div id="apDiv5"><img src="mole.png" width="902" height="320" alt="mole"></div>
<form action="form-to-email.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_self" class="form" id="mail" title="mail">
      <h2><br>
      Free Estimate</h2><table width="234" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" summary="form">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"> <label>Name
              <input name="Name" type="text" class="space" id="Name">
              <br>
             </label>          </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"> <label>Email
              <input name="Email" type="text" class="space" id="Email">
              <br>
             </label>          </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"> <label>Street
              <input name="Street" type="text" class="space" id="Street">
              <br>
             </label>          </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"> <label>Phone
              <input name="Phone" type="text" class="space" id="Phone">
              <br>
             </label>          </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"> <label>Zip
      <input name="zip" type="text" class="space" id="zip">
              <br>
             </label>          </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row">      <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" class="sub1" id="Sub" style="button" value="Submit">
    </div></td>
  </tr>
      </table>

</form>

<div class= "column1"><img src="/writing.png" width="493" height="653" alt="writing">
  <div id="apDiv14">
    <h3>Seven-Step         Fertilization Program<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free estimate widget on the right hand side has a set height on line 147 of index.css

Just reduce this to remove the extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Like Drawdesign mentioned, it looks like you're declaring a set height on `.form` in your index.css file.  Alter that height, and you'll alter that gap.